# How to Access the Provider List - Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have a Kivy program I am creating.

When I run the program without `sudo`, I get a

`[WARNING] [MTD        ] Unable to open device "/dev/input/event6". Please ensure you have the appropraite permissions.`

Although this happens, the application works exactly as intended. But, as I am developing, I need my program to use `sudo` so instead of having to switch between the program and terminal to type the password - I was thinking of executing the program as `sudo python3 name.py`.

I then get a

`[INFO   ] [MTD        ] </dev/input/event6> range position X is 1 - 2944`

I used `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` to learn that input6 is:

```
...
N: Name="PS/2 Generic Mouse"
S: Sysfs=/devices/playform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
...
```

Now, I get weird input such as the mouse is being pressed down even when I don't click, e.g.:

1. Button presses happening when my mouse is at least 100 pixels away
2. `TextInput`s being highlighted even though I am nowhere near them

**Question:** Is there a way to either:

1. Turn off `probefsys so it can't open the device and I can run my application is if it doesn't have` sudo` attached in the config/post-start/etc

- OR -

2. Remove the specific device?

Note: I'm not 100% sure if a laptop has an affect, but I wonder if it is because of the mousepad? I haven't tried with a USB-mouse (seems unlikely but possible).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to turn off the input device by setting

```
Config.set('input', '%(name)s', '')
```

It is then provided an unknown provider and the mouse + keyboard work as intended without their fancy-dancy input providers :)